# Function declared in template.php doesnt get loaded in a page's content

Tags: theming

I have created a function called `generate_rss()`, but when I call that function inside a page using PHP code as input format, I get the following error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function generate_rss().

I am using Drupal 6. Does anybody know how to fix this?

```
<?php  
     echo generate_rss('http://rss feed url here');
?>
```

I think template.php is loaded after the page's contents are rendered.
If I use

```
`include_once( 'path to theme/template.php');`
```

there will be no fatal error.

Comment: Clear your cache. http://drupal.org/node/337176, make sure the theme containing the `generate_rss` function is active.

Comment: @NikhilM I tried that, but no change

Comment: please post your code

Comment: @AndrewWelch I pasted code